# ScrollIntoView inside an iFrame Not Working on iPhone's Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone

This code is meant to scroll to an element "timeline" when you click on anything of the class "modalButton."

The code is located inside an iFrame.

It works perfectly on Chrome in my desktop, but it's not working inside the iPhone (both Chrome & Safari). Is there any fix to this or alternate methods to make this work?

```
<script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
            $( ".modalButton" ).click(function() {
                    document.getElementById("timeline").scrollIntoView();
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: In my testing, it works correctly only if the parent frame is currently scrolled to the top. This seems like a bug - I think it used to work in a previous version of iOS, though I'm not certain.

Comment: I came up with a workaround using parent.postMessage and a listener in the parent frame which would scroll accordingly. Obviously this is only possible if you have some ability to implement the listener in the parent.